# Can .py files be debugged in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010

I'm new to Python and am playing around with Python Tools for Visual Studio but I can't seem to find a way to use the VS debugger on .py files.  It seems like the files have to be compiled to .pyc of part of a VS Solution to use the debugger.

This is a bummer because I would like to write standalone .py scripts in a text editor and use the VS debugger as needed.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: https://pytools.codeplex.com/

Comment: You can manually compile a .pyc file by `import py_compile; py_compile.compile('filename.py')`

Comment: @SeanCheshire My question states that I'm already using Python Tools. That's what I have a question about.

Comment: UPDATE: I've since learned that it is possible from this post on Scott Hanselman's blog: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OneOfMicrosoftsBestKeptSecretsPythonToolsForVisualStudioPTVS.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to use Visual Studio for debugging, consider the pdb module: http://aymanh.com/python-debugging-techniques

Edit: 
I spent some time playing around with Attach Process, but couldn't get it to work. My suggestion: have the .py file in a VS solution, edit with your favorite text editor, then switch back to VS, and in the Solution Explorer tab, right click on the file and select Start With Debugging.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but the pbd isn't nearly as user-friendly as the VS debugger.

Comment: I've never used the VS debugger. Learning about pdb made my life a lot easier. I guess I'll have to check out the VS debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Debugging a dynamic language like python is a little different
(I assume you mean you want to debug python code and not the C code in the python interpreter.)

There are some good free tools to use VS2010 with python which I have used in the past - see [Python integration for Visual Studio 2010](http://pytools.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Can the tool you've linked me to debug non-compiled python files (.py)?

Comment: Yeah, that only works if the .py file is part of a larger Visual Studio Solution.

Comment: @Splendor - you would make a visual studio project of your python code. It doesn't have to be part of a c++ app (IIRC)